# Proving a Variation of the the Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I am trying to prove the following:

Let $X1, X2, . . .$ be positive, i.i.d. r.v.s with mean $\mu$ and finite
variance $\sigma^2$, and let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k$
, $n \ge 1$. Show that $\frac{S_n − n\mu}{\sqrt{S_n}} \to N(0,b^2)$ in distribution and determine the value of $b^2$.

I figured the proof is somewhat analogous to the proof of the CLT.  Following along with what my text has provided for the proof of CLT, I am trying to show that $\varphi_{\frac{S_n − n\mu}{\sqrt{S_n}}} \to e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2b^2}$.   By the properties of sums of r.v.s, $\frac{S_n − n\mu}{\sqrt{S_n}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{X_{k}-\mu}{\sqrt{X_K}}$. Next,assuming WLOG that $\mu=0$ (if I'm allowed to do that? My book shows the proof with and without the assumption.  Not sure what to do in this case.), $\varphi_{\frac{S_n − n\mu}{\sqrt{S_n}}}=\varphi_{\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{S_n}}}$.  This is where I get stuck.  How do I move forward in showing this convergence when I have a characteristic function of the quotient of two random sums?

Comment: What is $S_n$? Is it a product or sum?

Comment: It is a sum.  Sorry for the typo.

Comment: The point is not to prove CLT directly (which is rare in exercises or exams) but apply it with Slutsky's theorem. $\mu$ cannot be assumed to and not equal to zero unless $X_1$ is almost surely zero.

Comment: According to your history you haven't accepted any answer. Is there any reason for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write 
$$\frac{S_n - n\mu}{\sqrt{S_n}} = \frac{S_n - n\mu}{\sqrt{n}\sigma}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{n}\sigma}{\sqrt{S_n}}.$$
where $\sigma^2 = \text{Var}(X_1)$.

By CLT, $\frac{S_n - n\mu}{\sqrt{n}\sigma} \Rightarrow N(0, 1)$. By WLLN, $\frac{S_n}{n} \to \mu$ in probability. The result follows from the Slutsky's theorem. Clearly, $b^2 = \frac{\sigma^2}{\mu}$.

Comment: Why does the resulting quantity after the application of Slutsky's theorem converge to $N(0,b^2)$ instead of just $N(0,b)$? Doesn't $\frac{\sqrt{n}\sigma}{\sqrt{S_n}} \to \frac{\sigma}{\mu}$?

Comment: @user75514 $\frac{S_n}{n} \to \mu$ in probability implies $\frac{\sqrt{n}\sigma}{\sqrt{S_n}} = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{S_n/n}} \to \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{\mu}}$ in probability, in view of continuous mapping theorem.

Comment: So multiplying by $b=\frac{\sqrt{n} \sigma}{\sqrt{S_n}}$ causes the quantity to converge to $N(0,b^2)$ by Slutsky's theorem?

Comment: @user75514 Basically you are right, but $\frac{\sqrt{n}\sigma}{\sqrt{S_n}}$ is not $b$, it converges to $b$ in probability.

Comment: Right.  Thank you very much!